# Liquibase recreate constraints

Tags: java, database, database-migration, liquibase

We are using liquibase for db migrations and we got following case: when we started implementing project we didn't add cascade delete for foreign keys and now we get situation where we need to do that. I have two options how to handle that:

1. Drop and create all constraints
2. Update existing ones.

We are not in production yet so which option is the best for me? Also in the second case we'll have to recreate QA db and all devs dbs as a cons but it will make our liquibase change log more readable for future...

Comment: "best" in what sense?

Comment: like a best practice or something like that

Comment: If you are not in production I would go for option 1.

Comment: yeap, I was also thinking about this option. You added some confidence.:)